# Exception "if" so that the button is displayed only when the data is completed

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, prestashop

I need help adding an "if" exception to my code so that the "button" is displayed on the page only when the data in "$customtab.description" is completed in the module. Not all items have this completed and the button is displayed everywhere, but I would like it to be displayed only when the data is completed.

```
<div id="custom-tab-{$customtab.id_tab|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="tab-pane fade in revealOnScroll animated fadeInUp">{$customtab.description nofilter}</div>
        {hook h='displayAfterProductThumbs' product=$product}
        <button onclick="iframetrailer()" id="buttoniframe">Fullscreen</button>
        </div>
```

I would like to ask for help in adding "if" in such a way that the "button" will not be displayed on item pages that do not have "$customtab.description" completed.

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="custom-tab-{$customtab.id_tab|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="tab-pane fade in revealOnScroll animated fadeInUp">{$customtab.description nofilter}</div>
        {hook h='displayAfterProductThumbs' product=$product}
        <button onclick="iframetrailer()" id="buttoniframe">Fullscreen</button>
        </div>
 {if !empty({$customtab.description)}
<button onclick="iframetrailer()" id="buttoniframe">Fullscreen</button>
<style>
 button {
   display: none}
</style>{/if}
```

The button is disabled, regardless of whether the table has data or not

Comment: What is your definition of "completed" - does it just mean that `$customtab.description` must not be _empty_, or something else? PrestaShop uses Smarty as template engine, if I am not mistaken - so such a condition to check if there is any value at all, should not be that hard to write, with the help of the documentation, https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl ...?

Comment: I would like the "button" to not be displayed when the table is empty

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would never suggest adding an style to a whole type like "button" just to do it for one specific button, specially so if this is supposed to be an addition to some other page, like a Hook that add your section of template into a bigger page.

The reason is pretty simple, it will apply to every other button on the page, not just the one you want.

But there is also the fact that the Theme button style most likely have priority anyway, so your button will not actually be hidden unless you add a "!important" to your style, which is another thing you should usually avoid.

So what you should do is to use the "#buttoniframe" in your style instead of "button"  or if you have more than 1 button, give your buttons a class like class="descriptionButton" then style it using ".descriptionButton" instead.

Putting that aside,

you don't even need to use styling or JavaScript to solve this problem.

Your code is showing duplicate button, one that always show and one that is inside the if condition.

What you need to do is to remove what you added, and just replace the button with the if condition, so the old button is inside the condition.

Full code would be something like this:

```
<div id="custom-tab-{$customtab.id_tab|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="tab-pane fade in revealOnScroll animated fadeInUp">{$customtab.description nofilter}</div>
{hook h='displayAfterProductThumbs' product=$product}
{if $customtab.description != ''}
    <button onclick="iframetrailer()" id="buttoniframe">Fullscreen</button>
{/if}
</div>
```

But keep in mind, This condition is for when description is empty, like an empty string. but if this value is sometimes undefined or null, this can create an error, then you use isset instead or use both of them like this:

```
{if isset($customtab.description) && $customtab.description != ''}
    <button onclick="iframetrailer()" id="buttoniframe">Fullscreen</button>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! You're the best!